# Winter Bash hats are shown behind the profile photo

Tags: bug, status-norepro, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

The avatar is hiding the Winter Bash hats when placing the hat, during its control (changing its location, size, etc.). In past it always shown in front of the avatar.

Is there any way figure out this to show in front of the avatar?

[image]

---

- Browser: Safari `Version 14.0.1`

---

But on my profile page, hat is shown in front of the avatar, but at top right corner it is behind.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how the meta post "show off your hats" is relevant. What exactly is the bug? The fact that the avatar is hiding the hat when placing the hat? If so, please remove noise from the bug report, it's totally not relevant and only confusing. If that's not the bug, please explain what is the actual bug.

Comment: @ShadowtheHatterWizard I tried to update my question in more clear way

Comment: Thanks, better now. Can't reproduce here, using Chrome so it's likely browser issue, maybe userscript issue. Please add what browser you're using, and if you have any userscripts, disable them and try again. (If you find which is causing the problem you can self answer so others will disable it as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using [dark reader](https://darkreader.org), in order to enable dark mode.

When its disabled the issue is resolved. Mainly when dark mode is enabled, it causes hats to be seen in behind of the avatar.

Comment: There is stack overflow dark mode, on a similar note.

Comment: @cornonthecob yeah, but for other sites, no choice but to use userscripts.